# Alternative to the CLI command "more"

Tags: command-line

I have search google over and over looking for an alternative to the command `more`. Something that uses `ncurses`, etc. I know that something exists as I had it on my laptop before I upgraded to 14.04 yesterday, during the upgrade for some reason it disappeared.

The one I was using on my laptop had a blue bar across the bottom and allowed the use of `PgUp` and `PgDwn` to go back and forth. It had already made itself default as when I asked for details during the upgrade to 14.04 it displayed those details using it instead of `more`. The problem is I do not know the name of this software for the life of me.

I've searched google for many terms while looking for this replacement but haven't found anything as of yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `less` is installed as an replacement for `more`. It supports <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDown</kbd> but doesn't have the blue bar.

The one with the blue bar is `most`.

Comment: I was just about to ask it lol